# Image watermark in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am using yii\imagine\Image extension and want to add a watermark to my image.

Here's my code:

```
$watermarkImage = '@webroot/../images/watermark.png';
$image = '@webroot/../slike/img-4.jpg';
Image::watermark($image, $watermarkImage);
```

After this code is executed, nothing happens. What am I missing here?

Comment: In your extension you need the  path or the url?

Comment: @scaisEdge Either ImageInterface, resource or a string containing file path

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right paths? Where are your images located? It should be inside your `web/` folder somewhere. If it's in web/images then you might want to use this path: `@web/images/watermark.png` and `@web/images/slike/img-4.jpg`.

Comment: I'm using the right paths. If I try with `@web` instead of `@webroot` it says that image with that path is not found.

Comment: FYI: Imagine extension has just been updated a couple of days ago. It breaks some backwards compatibility but AFAIK it shouldn't affect watermark.
http://www.yiiframework.com/news/117/imagine-extension-version-2-1-0-released/

Comment: @pappfer It doesn't affect watermark..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `::watermark()` function creates the new image but doesn't automatically saves it. The function returns a `Imagine\Gd\Image` object. This object can be used to save the new files.

```
$watermarkImage = '@webroot/../images/watermark.png';
$image = '@webroot/../slike/img-4.jpg';
// Store the Image object in a variable
$newImage = Image::watermark($image, $watermarkImage);
// Call the save function to write the file to the disk.
$newImage->save(Yii::getAlias('@webroot/../slike/img-4-watermark.jpg'));
```

Comment: any idea how could we make it centered ?